# In YII2 validation rules I need something opposite to compare

Tags: yii2, yii2-validation

I need to compare new password with old one that they are unequal
it`s a code where new password and password confirm compares, but what I can do for my matter?

```
['password_confirm', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password_new', 'message'=>"пароль и подтверждение пароля не совпадает" ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a resolusion:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
['password_new', 'in', 'range' => [$this->password_current], 'not' => true, 'message'=>"new password equals with old one"]
];
    }
```